# Stack inside column not working. What should I use instead?

Tags: flutter

[image: App view]

I want to create this widget. The pseudocode I tried is just like this:

- Column

  - Container (My Widget)

    - Column

      - Image
      - Stack

        - Message Text
        - Positioned

          - Status Text

Constraints:

- Status must look like it stays inside the text widget. But it shouldn't be on it.
- Text and image sizes are not fixed !!!

Problem: Stack inside column without size is not working. So status text appears under the text widget as centered.

```
return MessageBallon(
  directory: message.direction,
  childElement: Column(
    children: [
      message.hasMedia
          ? Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * .05),
              child: CustomMedia(
                src: message.media,
              ),
            )
          : const SizedBox(),
      Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 13,
              top: 18,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: width * .53),
                  child: Text(
                    message.content,
                    style: TextStyles.normalTextBlack,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    message.messageDate,
                    style: TextStyles.detailText,
                  ),
                ),
                message.direction == SmsDirection.incoming
                    ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: messageStatus,
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include your current snippet ?

Comment: Can you add your code. So, we can suggest changes.

Comment: I've added my code now.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Scaffold with FloatingActionButton for your status.

Rest Image and Text can be inside a column.

You can achieve something like the below only with these widgets.

[image]

Comment: I need to use my widget more than once inside the page. And every widget must contain status.